# How can I parse a PDB file in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, pdb

I would like to create a function that can parse the following from any PDB file:

1. The helix id of each helix and the length
2. The sheetID, number of strands, and the total number of residues

---

```
f=open('5ogb.pdb')
lines=f.readlines()

print lines[337] 
print lines[338]

print "helixID= AA2"
```

How can I improve this code please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a "pdb file" in this case? Because when I hear that, I think of debugging information, but it sounds like that's not what your file contains, but rather some sort of genetic data?

Comment: It's a [protein data bank](https://www.rcsb.org/pdb/static.do?p=file_formats/pdb/index.html) file, which holds 3D structure data (and data related to the experiments used to get such data) of proteins

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch of different packages that can do this. I would use the `Bio.PDB` module from biopython. Here's a [tutorial](https://biopython.org/wiki/The_Biopython_Structural_Bioinformatics_FAQ) to help get you started.